# How to convert list of JSON object to PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to convert a JSON string in variable to PySpark DataFrame on Databricks.

I have a payload coming from API. It is a list of JSON objects hold on a variable called `response_list`. The variable is JSON object with type of `class 'str'>`:

```json
[{"sentiment":"neutral","sentiment_confidence_score":0.8585},{"sentiment":"neutral","sentiment_confidence_score":0.7861}]
```

I am trying to parse this into a PySpark dataframe so each object here is a single row. The desired output is below.

| pyspark_column |
| --- |
| {"sentiment":"neutral","sentiment_confidence_score":0.8585} |
| {"sentiment":"neutral","sentiment_confidence_score":0.7861} |

What I try is:

```py
dfJson = sc.parallelize(response_list).map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
dfJson = spark.read.json(dfJson)
dfJson.show(truncate = False)
```

It throws me this error of missing argument:

```
File "<command-3646528696964905>", line 79, in json_parse
    dfJson = sc.parallelize(response_list).map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
TypeError: parallelize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

I have spent nearly whole day on this. When I copy paste that list of JSON into a JSON Validator it says, this JSON is valid. So I assume format is correct. But I couldn't figure out how to convert this to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is like answering my own question. But I finally solved it. If moderators see appropriate they can delete the question. I parse json string into a list of dictionaries. Then I created a Spark Dataframe using list of dicts. I am sure there are more efficient way of doing this. But this works for now.

```py
# empty list to store dict items
list_of_dicts = []
        
response_list_dumped = json.loads(response_list)
for d in response_list_dumped:
    list_of_dicts.append(d)
        
ResponseDF = spark.createDataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

output is like this:

```
|sentiment|sentiment_confidence_score|
|negative |0.9065                    |
|neutral  |0.6207                    |
|positive |0.6734                    |
|positive |0.5663                    |
|neutral  |0.8788                    |
|neutral  |0.9155                    |
|neutral  |0.5019                    |
|negative |0.6617                    |
|neutral  |0.69                      |
|neutral  |0.8335                    |
```